# How to send updated state in axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to send post request using axios in Reactjs.

I have two component a `timer` component and `App` component and in App component i am trying to submit a form and send an axios call when i fetch the time from Timer component and save itinto `counter` state

I have written a condition if counter is true then update my state and then further send the post request

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-greider-u4jlu?file=/src/App.js:1067-1068)
here is a handle submit code:

```
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("handleSubmit");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter) {
      console.log(counter);
      const url = `url string`;
      setState({
        ...state,
        lastn: {
          attestedTime: myDateFunc(),
          time: counter
        }
      });
      console.log(state);
      axios
        .post(url, state)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

The problem is when counter is true its not update the state which causes error while send axios request.

I have consoled each and every thing but still it fails.
It seems there is lot of rendering.

Comment: what do you have on the line where you call `useState()` ?

Comment: hi @Nathanael you can check on link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using class components, you can make the reuqest after the state has been set. Something like this:

```
this.setState({
  ...state,
  lastn: {
    attestedTime: myDateFunc(),
    time: counter
  }
}, () => {
  axios
    .post(url, state)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Since you did set the `react-hooks` tag, I guess that approach is not what you need. In your case, I suggest saving new state in some temporary variable and than passing that variable to `axios`. Like this:

```
const newState = {
  ...state,
  lastn: {
    attestedTime: myDateFunc(),
    time: counter
  }
};

setState(newState);
axios
  .post(url, newState)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to, but I always get the error due to the (I guess) URL. Try my solution on some with some real URL.

Comment: yup you might get error due to url. so can you give a demo

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-framework-irugu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @radovix Thankyou so much but can you tell Why my component is rendered twice ?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` can be executed asynchronously by React, to optimize the rendering process. For cases like this one, it can also take a callback function that is guaranteed to be executed after updating the state.

For example:

```
this.setState({
    name:'value' 
},() => {
    console.log(this.state.name);
});
```

in this case `console.log` will be executed after setting the `name` variable.

see the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: By the i am using hooks

Comment: i saw it. i didn't understand it from the code you posted. i am having a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-robinson-505yk?file=/src/App.js saving the state as suggested in another answer. otherise you need to do the network call in a useEffect that runs on state change